# crop unwanted black space of image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have a set of grayscale images, like this:

[image]

This is an example image as I cannot post the original image. Each image has an area with a texture, a pure white watermark (pos), and lots of unwanted black space.

Ideally this image should be cropped to:

[image]

The watermark can be slightly different in each image, but is always very thin pure white text.

The pictures can look very different, here is another example

[image]

this one only needs cropping on the left

[image]

another one:

[image]

this one needs to be cropped on top and bottom:

[image]

and another one

[image]

this one needs to be cropped at the top and right. Note that I left the watermark in this picture. Ideally the watermark would be removed as well, but I guess it is easier without.

here is a picture of the watermark how it looks in reality.

[image]

The images vary in size, but are usually large (over 2000x2000).

I am looking for a solution in python (cv2 maybe).

my first idea was to use something like this:
[Python & OpenCV: Second largest object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552765/python-opencv-second-largest-object)

but this solution code fails for me

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/41761313/2836621

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks Mark, your solution is great and works, but I now realized that I need on-the-fly processing of the images and this has to be done in python.

Comment: use threshold (+maybe dilate + erode) + contour extraction + bounding box of biggest contour + subimaging that biggest contour bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I work in C# and C++ and don't work in python but can suggest you the logic.

You need to run two scan of the image, one row wise and other columns wise.

Since you said the unwanted part of image is always black, just read the pixel values in both scan. If the color of all the pixels in a certain row is black then you can elemminate or delete that row. Similar steps can be followed for column wise scanning.

Now we cannot just eleminate the rows and columns so easily, so just note down the redundant rows and columns and then you can crop your image using following code:( I will code in C# with emgucv library but it is easy to understand for python)

```
Mat original_image = new Mat();
Rect ROI = new Rect(x,y,width,height);
Mat image_needed_to_crop = new Mat(original_image,ROI);
```

This code just extracts only the region of interest from the original image.